# I cant convert list<object[]> to list <T[]> in C#

Tags: c#, object, generics, typeconverter

I have the following final code:

```
SqlDataReader dataReader;
dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
// var list = new List<string[]>();
List<T[]> list = new List<T[]>();

while (dataReader.Read())
{
   // var row = new string[dataReader.FieldCount];
    //object[] row new object;
    T[] bass;
    object[] row = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];
    dataReader.GetValues(row);
    bass = (T[]) Convert.ChangeType(row,typeof(T[]));
    list.Add(bass);
}
```

I kept tried to convert an object array to a T generic type array in different ways, but i didn't make it. For the earlier code i get a runtime error: object must implement IConvertible.
I put a constraint for the generic type when i defined the class:

```
class Cclass<T>: Iinterface<T> where T:IConvertible
{  
    //body 
}
```

I'm open to other suggestions that can fulfill my goal of casting to generic array.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use *Linq*:

```
  bass = row
    .Select(x => (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T)))
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I get the same error:Cannot implicitly convert type 'object[]' to 'T[]'

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert an array of `T1` to a collection of `T2`, even if `T1` can be cast to `T2`. Look up http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx. A simpler solution would be to iterate through each object in the row and cast them individually.

Comment: I didn't know this fact regarding the conversion between two collections. Iterating and casting individually is working, indeed.Thank you very much for your answer!